# How to make the batch file for these files

Tags: batch-file

I have many text files like File 1, File 2 etc. in different folders.
Say in File 1 the lines are like this...

```
YESBANK,20171016,09:20:00,373.95,374.20,372.25,372.40,213136
YESBANK,20171016,09:25:00,372.30,372.45,371.30,372.00,128141
```

I want to edit these lines in the following form..

```
YESBANK-EQ,20171016,09:20:00,373.95,374.20,372.25,372.40,213136
YESBANK-EQ,20171016,09:25:00,372.30,372.45,371.30,372.00,128141
```

Similarly in File 2 the lines are like this...

```
ABAN,20171016,09:20:00,189.35,190.10,189.35,189.80,63803
ABAN,20171016,09:25:00,189.80,190.70,189.55,190.50,47039
```

I want to edit these lines in the following form..

```
ABAN-EQ,20171016,09:20:00,189.35,190.10,189.35,189.80,63803
ABAN-EQ,20171016,09:25:00,189.80,190.70,189.55,190.50,47039
```

how to do these jobs in a single command by a batch file?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask].

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Actually Jeff I have no knowledge of making batch files. Actually I have many files like file 1, file 2 ..etc in each files there are such type of lines (as mentioned in the query) in many numbers like 375 or 374...so can you please help me?

Comment: @Indrajit, please update your question by clicking on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46769262/edit), to include your folder structure and file specification. Without those any answer given would need to be manipulated by yourself to suit those pieces of information. As you have no knowledge of batch files, this would be almost impossible for you.

Comment: Indrajit: If you simply ask for and receive "prepackaged" solutions, you will never become able to create your own. You should do some research and learn how batch files work, and what some alternatives are. For learning Batch, I recommend [searching for tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+batch+tutorial); once you understand the basics, you'll also find that [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/) is a good reference site.

Answer (score 0):

Probably 1 command line like:

`msr -p folder1,folder2,file1,fileN -f "^file-\d+\.(txt|log)$" -t "^([^,]+)" -o "$1-EQ" -R`

This will replace files like `file-1.txt`, `file-2.log` in `folder1`/`folderN`.

- If you want to backup, add `-K` like `-R -K` or `-RK` etc.
- If they're in root folder like `D:\Root,E:\Root` (may has sub/descendant folders like `folder1`, `folder2`, `folder3`, etc), use `-r` to recusively search and replace:

  `msr -rp D:\Root,E:\Root -f "^file-\d+\.(txt|log)$" -t "^(\w+)" -o "$1-EQ" -R`
  [image: Replace files recursively]

[`msr.exe`/`msr.gcc*`](https://github.com/qualiu/msr/tree/master/tools) is a single exe tool (about 1.6MB) for Windows/Linux to search and replace files, in [my open project](https://github.com/qualiu/msr). Too see the usages and examples just run the exe or see online docs like built-in doc [msr on Windows](https://qualiu.github.io/msr/usage-by-running/msr-Windows.html). You can filter file name (`-f`/`--nf`), folder/directory name (`-d`/`--nd`), file size(`--s1`/`--s2`), file modify time/last-write-time (`--w1`, `--w2`), full path pattern (`--pp`/`--np`) etc.

Comment: Thanks Quanmao for your sincere help. Actually Jeff I have no knowledge of making batch files. Actually I have many files like file 1, file 2 ..etc in each files there are such type of lines (as mentioned in the query) in many numbers like 375 or 374...so can you please help me?

Comment: I have downloaded your file from this link https://sourceforge.net/projects/avasattva/?source=typ_redirect...but after that I cannot understand how to use it? Please help me

Comment: Method-1: Just call your saved path (if it's `d:\tools\msr.exe`) : `d:\tools\msr.exe -p folder1,folder2,folderN -f "^file-\d+\.(txt|log)$" -t "^([^,]+)" -o "$1-EQ" -R`

Comment: **Method-2** (Recommended): Add the directory `d:\tools` to the system environment variable `PATH`.  then you can call at anywhere and use `msr` or `msr.exe` (just like `findstr`.exe)

Comment: For your first question: (1) Many files and folders: can you tell me what's their folders (and root folders if have) ? I want to know the folders and file name features, this can be solved.
(2) What's `many numbers` and `375` `374` ? Do you mean that you only want to replace `YESBANK` to `YESBANK-EQ` **if the line contains both** `YESBANK` **and** `375`/`374` ?

Comment: Seems like an awful lot of work for something that can be done in a one-liner in batch with no external software.

Comment: @SomethingDark:  Yeah, his requirement not so simple.  @IndrajitChakraborty: If so, you can use `-t "^([^,]+)(.*)(374|375)" -o "$1-EQ$2$3" xxx` or `-t "^([^,]+)(.*)(37[4-5])" -o "$1-EQ$2$3"` etc.  And about `how to make a batch file`: Just save the command line (`msr -p xxx -t xxx -o xxx ... `) into a file (like `my-test.bat` or `my-test.cmd`)

Comment: His requirement is literally just to split the lines on commas and add `-EQ` to the first token. That's a `for /f` loop with the `"tokens=1,* delims=,"` options given.

Comment: @Quanmao. Yes I can bring the detail in mail through attachment. My email id is indraji2001@gmail.com. Can you just send a Hi! ..in reply mode I will tell you the problem in detail

Comment: I've sent a mail to you. If you've not received, ping me: qualiu @ microsoft.com

Comment: @Quanmao, so far of the 29 answers you've provided in less than 7 weeks of membership, only 3 have not specifically linked to your MSR utility. In my opinion, 90% of all of your answers are spam, moreso because the OP's are generally not looking for third party executable files in their questions!

Comment: @Compo: Do you mean I should stop answering such questions? I just thought this tool like **grep** and **sed** can help saving people's time. If these're considered as spam, I'll stop answering such questions from now on. Should I delete the no-score or no-effect answers ?

Comment: @qualiu @ microsoft.com ...sent

Comment: @SomethingDark 
His requirement is literally just to split the lines on commas and add -EQ to the first token. That's a for /f loop with the "tokens=1,* delims=," options given..then what is your solution....? I am badly searching for this problem

Comment: That _is_ the solution. How could you read that and then **not** immediately search Google for `cmd for /f split string into token`?

Comment: I have got the real solution from  Quanmao....really my problem got solved...a single cmd with a batch file solved the problem really his tool msr is very effective

Comment: Thanks @IndrajitChakraborty ! Glad to hear that! Hope this small exe can help saving your daily work time.

Comment: I can say that the tool developed by Quanmao (msr.exe) is really powerful. I makes the jib easy for a peson even who do not have the harcore knowledge in batch file. Personally I thanks him due to his ability to understand my problem and to give the realtime solution. Hope many people will get benefit from him. I really wish the best for him. His tool can perform many jobs in the automated way and a person who does not have any knowledge in batch file can handle this tool comfortably.

Comment: Thanks @IndrajitChakraborty ! For complicated or advanced scenarios, please use [**msr.exe**](https://github.com/qualiu/msr/tree/master/tools) together with [**nin.exe**](https://github.com/qualiu/msr/tree/master/tools) which is for **lines/keys set operation** (get difference or intersection key set or line set between files or file and pipe, **N**ot-or-**IN**-latter file/pipe) with **msr.exe** which is to **M**atch,**S**earch,**R**eplace files/pipe blocks/lines. You can also download these 2 small exe tools through https://sourceforge.net/projects/avasattva/

Comment: @Quanmao thanks...I am not the master like you in this area..but one thing I have noted my problem is getting solved using your tool. I am now really surprised to know the power of batch files...